# Grails baked-in testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, seam

I read article saying

> Testing support baked-in : Testing is
>   a priority and first-class citizen in
>   Grails. Grails promotes testing; and
>   provides utilities to make testing
>   easier — from low level unit tests to
>   high level functional tests. In
>   addition, Grails is not married to a
>   particular testing framework. You can
>   use JUnit, Spock, EasyB, Geb,
>   Selenium, Canoo etc. Any testing
>   framework can be made to work with
>   Grails (by writing a plugin that hooks
>   testing framework with Grails testing
>   infrastructure).

Does this mean that I can test Grails just like any other Java EE framework? Is that block of text saying nothing(like Grails have integration with jUnit) or is there anything special about Grails testing?

**EDIT:**

How does it compare to SeamTest?

Answer (score 5):

I would say that Grails supports testing by means of a folder structure that already contains folders for unit and integration tests, and its commands help out with test writing. When you create a domain class or controller, for instance, it automatically creates test stubs for you. It also has commands to run all tests, run unit/integration tests only or run individual tests - these create reports for you automatically in the test folder.

You can also find a lot of plugins that support testing - there is a good functional test plugin that uses HtmlUnit to test actual requests. There is also a Selenium plugin.

My overall experience with Grails has been very positive and I highly recommend it as a framework.

I hope this helps.

Comment: so its like Maven? I don't see anything amazing in your post(no offence) that would make me choose Grails if I wanted a very testable framework. I was expecting something extra, at least something like SeamTest.

Comment: Don't worry, none taken :-) I find a lot of similarities between grails and maven in fact. In terms of testability there is just the extra stubbing, but this can easily be added to Maven too. I would say that the true strength of grails is not in testability, but in the concise power of Groovy, dynamic language support (also via Groovy) and Rails-like scaffolding and general approach.

Answer (score 4):

As Matthew pointed out, the testing infrastructure is all set up.  The directory layout is defined and tests can be run through the grails script.

Overall, the testing environment of grails and SeamTest aren't that different.  They both have unit tests sans database, and integration tests that has the whole stack.  The differences are mostly of a java vs. groovy nature.

Just like SeamTest provides a layer over TestNG, grails has a layer over JUnit, that provides similar support.  [grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/GrailsUnitTestCase.html) and [groovy.util.GroovyTestCase](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html) are good starting points to see how they compare.

In my opinion, where grails really stands out is in its mocking support.  It uses groovy to provide very flexible mocking.  In particular, you can dynamically override methods with mock versions directly on classes and objects, so there's no need to create mock classes.  The framework provides shortcuts for mocking out the whole ORM layer, which allows you easily test higher level components without the overhead of the database.

Take a look at the [manual's chapter on testing](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html) for some concrete examples.